# Checkout page is blank, link has vanished and the cart button top has also vanished.

Tags: checkout, cart

Everything was fine until the Checkout page went blank and then link has vanished and the cart button top has also vanished. Then If I add a product into the cart and then it goes to the cart page its just blank.

Compilation is disabled, mage_cart is enabled.

Please help

Comment: Surely you must have made some changes for this to happen if everything was fine beforehand?

Comment: The last extension I installed was a blog one, I will take a look if any traces were left.

Comment: Otherwise try and retrace your steps and re-install those extensions until you get it to work again. BTW you should really click 'add comment' when replying, else you're posting an answer.

Comment: I cant see any traces of the exension left behind

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, just removed local.xml then it worked. That was strange.